# Python binding for clutter-gtk and clutter-gsk

Tags: python, gtk, clutter

I'm using python and want to embed gtk3 widgets in clutter stage. However, it seems [pyclutter-gtk](http://git.clutter-project.org/cgit.cgi?url=bindings/pyclutter-gtk/) and [pyclutter-gsk](http://git.clutter-project.org/cgit.cgi?url=bindings/pyclutter-gst/) has been stopped for a while. Is there any alternative binding that we can use in python?
I tried google but with no luck. There's only one project(http://code.google.com/p/pyclutter-widgets/) seems interesting but it's inactive for a year...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All python bindings for gtk3 and clutter have been moved to the introspection-based *pygobject*; you should be able to use Clutter-Gtk and Clutter-Gst from pygobject >= 2.30 by simply doing:

`from gi.repository import GtkClutter`

You can follow the documentation on the [Gnome wiki entry for IntrospectionPorting](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works for Clutter, but I got ImportError when importing ClutterGtk. FYI, I'm using ubuntu 11.10 with gnome3 and python 2.7. I've installed libclutter-gtk-1.0*. Any clue?

Comment: Well... **GtkClutter** works but not _ClutterGtk_. I figured that I've installed gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a GtkClutter stage and scrollActor to a Gtk.HBox with Clutter-gtk 1.2.x and python-3.x

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GtkClutter, Clutter   

class EmbeddedGtkClutterStageWithScrollActor(Gtk.Window): 

    def __init__(self):
        super(EmbeddedGtkClutterStage, self).__init__()

        # Initialise GtkClutter
        GtkClutter.init(sys.argv)


        self.connect('destroy', lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.set_default_size(1024, 768)
        self.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))

        display = Gdk.Display.get_default()
        screen = display.get_default_screen()
        css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        css_provider.load_from_path('style.css')
        context = Gtk.StyleContext()
        context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION) 


        hbox = Gtk.HBox(False, 2)
        vbox.add(hbox)

        # Create Clutter Stage 
        embed = GtkClutter.Embed()    

        hbox.add(embed)
        embed.set_size_request(900, 500)

        stage = embed.get_stage()
        # set stage color to black
        stage.set_color(Clutter.Color.new(0, 0, 0, 255))

        # Create a Scrollable Actor and add to the Stage
        scrollActor = Clutter.ScrollActor()

        scrollActor.set_scroll_mode(Clutter.ScrollMode.HORIZONTALLY)
        stage.add_actor(scrollActor)

        # scroll the scrollActor to x/y coords 
        point = Clutter.Point()
        point.x = 50
        point.y = 100
        scrollActor.scroll_to_point(point) 

        hbox.show_all()


EmbeddedGtkClutterStageWithScrollActor()
Gtk.main()
```